# Trying to use MAAS 2.1.3 to deploy Centos 7

Tags: maas

"Ubuntu MAAS 2.1.3" has several Ubuntu and Centos versions supported out of the box.

Our environment has a target version of Centos 7 for general deployment in the lab.

Ubuntu MAAS is working great for every supported system, except Centos 7.  Centos 7 deployment is failing because the network is disabled by default during installation.  So Ubuntu MAAS deployment works great, until it boots into Centos, then cloud-init stalls out trying to pull data from the Ubuntu MAAS server, without a functional network.  It lists the available network ports to the screen, and "up" is false for everything except the loopback interface.

Because centos 7 is supported by Ubuntu MAAS, I'm assuming that this worked at one point, but Centos changed something that broke it (or I am using hardware that uses an unsupported ethernet interface (I'm using a stack of hp proliant dl360 g7's to get Ubuntu MAAS working before my new servers arrive)).  I'm assuming the hardware isn't the issue, as I can manually install centos7 on the dl360's with zero problems, but of course it prompts me to turn the network on.

Where is the script that I need to edit that is responsible for bringing the network up? I'm guessing I just need to tweak the code so that it brings up the network, but it is difficult to find documentation of where this code is.

Comment: #2 in the centos faq: https://wiki.centos.org/FAQ/CentOS7 And this: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2360884 might help too

Comment: "but Centos changed something that broke it" Yes and I would think that would be the changing names of NICs (as we too did in Ubuntu) from eth0 to hardware names.

Comment: Yeah 7.0 changes interface names AND sets all ports as disabled. I found the MAAS location to insert the kernel command line to cause centos7 to go back to the "eth0" naming convention, but I need to also add the commands to start the network.  The MAAS handoff of a finished deployment is ssh key based, there is no way to even log in from the console.  So if MAAS doesn't turn the network on, the deployment is a fail as the only login capability is network based.  But that change has supposedly always been in centos7, I'm not sure how it could have gotten broken if the deployment ever worked.

Comment: I think my main issue is the deployment scripts are not well documented, many things have changed.  I think they are somehow packaged into the centos installer image, so they run on first startup...  Or at least a switch in the image is flipped causing an additional file to be pulled over, while the deploying machine is still running the Ubuntu ephemeral image.  I just need help finding what to hack to insert a line to bring up eth0.

Comment: So the answer to my questions (without actually answering my main questions) is to simply try again every day until the daily build of the Centos 7 image works, then stop syncing updates.  The scripts I was looking for are in the Centos image.  The Centos image is not the standard common centos distribution, it is an image built by the Ubuntu team specifically for MAAS.